# What are the advantages of MySites in Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm attempting to justify this functionality to my boss.

So as the title says, what are the advantages of mySites in SharePoint 2007?

Answer (score 1):

We were exploring the use of MySites as a repository of useful information on the employees.  As an example, I could convey my skill set through MySites (i.e. ASP.NET, JavaScript, etc.) and then someone else could do a search for that skill set and be presented with people like myself.  You could do the same thing with project experience, etc..

We were also exploring the possibility of importing information from AD and our HR database, associating it with employee profiles in SharePoint, and then making that information accessible through search.  You could see the organizational hierarchy, phone numbers, departmental information, etc..

Lastly, individuals can use MySites as a way of sharing information (Word documents, etc.) with other employees.  This is an alternative to emailing documents, hosting them on network shares, creating shares on desktops, etc..

Unfortunately we hit a road block (huge changes in the company) that have put this initiative on hold - but we were really excited about doing this and it seemed like a real possibility as we began exploring the functionality in dev.

Comment: Did you ever implement this the way you like?

Comment: Unfortunately no - that company was acquired and the new owner had no interest in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

For me SharePoint 2007 MYSITE is a central location to manage and store users' documents, content, links, and contacts.

SO far I have not explored other possibilities.